# Huawei Ascend P1 is sending SMS automatically everyday

Tags: sms, huawei

I bought a Huawei Ascend P1 and installed some apps. But for the past 3-4 days, I see an alert that an SMS has been sent and 1.50 INR has been deducted. How will it unlock and send an SMS?

I found from my mobile carrier that the SMS was sent to the same number. The following apps have the `SEND_SMS` permission, but I am confused because most of them are system apps, and a few like WhatsApp & True Caller are trusted. I really don't understand what's going on as I see that the questions related to this topic seem different.

[image: apps 1]
[image: apps 2]

Comment: "Rayman Jungle Run" looks suspicious.

Comment: Rayman doesn't have SMS permission from the play store. Did you get a fake copy, or did you sideload an illegal one? That would be my first guess on it.

Comment: @RossC, Confirmed...It doesn't.

Comment: **Note:** As indicated by 3 answers, the real problem is indeed on Huawei. While Rayman Jungle Run is certainly suspicious, it's a red-herring on this question.

Answer (score 23):

The list of apps in your screenshot includes "Rayman Jungle Run". This doesn't have any reason to send SMS messages, and the [genuine game listed on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pastagames.ro1mobile) doesn't require that permission.

It seems likely that you've been taken in by a fake or *trojan* that pretends to be the game you wanted, but in fact sends SMS to premium numbers behind your back, to make money. This is commonplace if you try to download commercial games from game piracy sites. There are also sometimes quite convincing fakes on Google Play.

Uninstall the app immediately. If the messages stop, and you're convinced that was the culprit, you should report it to the site you downloaded it from. If you downloaded it from Google Play, then you can report it directly within the Play Store app, and Google will remove it.

If your country has a government agency responsible for policing premium phone and SMS services, you should report the app and the number it sent messages to to that agency. They'll want to know that the SMS number has been used for fraudulent purposes, and may be able to shut down the company that originated the scam.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer I'llcheck it.. but for my problem I got solution please see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found the problematical app. This is related to Huawei's app.

After searching/tracing the number, I found that the number the SMS was sent to was Huawei Server number. It will work like this:

When you put SIM card for the first time, it will auto send an SMS to that number for registering the start of warranty period. But in my case, I am facing network issues, so whenever my network disconnects & reestablishes, it will send SMS every time it happens. I only cannot figure out why it's still sending SMS if it's one time process.

Anyway, there is an app in my list called `com.android.huawei.gpms` which is responsible for this activity. So I simply go to **Settings - Apps - All - com.android.huawei.gpms - Disable**, and that weird problem was solved for now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not a any app or virus, It is defect of Huawei software, you need to install fix available at Huawei support->Download site "Auto Sms Fixed Software"
http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/Support/Downloads/

Answer (score 2):

As @saurin said, it is due to a bug, and they released update.

`Here is snapshot of reply email from Huawei with instructions.`

[image: Reply email from Huawei]

Comment: Glad it is fixed. Please mark your or @saurin's solution as answer.