# Tablet sending Message automatically to a fixed number (everyday)

Tags: sms

I have same problem as described in [My phone is sending SMS automatically everyday](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/53005/16575), but I have a Croma [CRX-1125](http://www.cromaretail.com/Croma-CRXT1125-3G-Calling-7%22-Tablet-%28White%29-pc-17920-162.aspx) tablet. It's deducting Rs 1.5 almost everyday, and it's sending message to Swipe telecom number. The Croma tablet is tied up with Swipe company; Croma doesn't have its own tablet.

Comment: I don't think the device makes any difference in this case, if it's an app causing the trouble. Have you checked your apps with *Permission manager*, as the linked question suggests? From the facts you provided, it's hard to see what could be the cause.

Comment: Check the permission manager as Izzy said, most times this happens due to an errant app. Have you side loaded any games, or anything not from a reputable store? The last time I saw this the person had a cracked copy of Rayman that was sending SMS (and sending their contacts, messages and personal information over the internet too). Actually it's worth pointing out there are plenty of rogue apps on the official stores (Play, Amazon etc) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force close the particular app/service that is causing this problem (That is the app/service that is sending that message).

And if possible, uninstall that app.

If uninstalling is not possible, you may need to `root` your phone to either

`uninstall`/`stop it from starting on bootup`/`stop it from sending message`.

Comment: Thanks all. I would try it. I have permission explorer. would send you soon the pic of that and then help me in that.