# Samsung sending SMS automatically on Idea Cellular (although no charge)

Tags: sms, samsung

I have two Samsung Galaxy Young Duos (GT-S6312) mobiles, both have Idea Connection. I noticed from last few days that my both mobile suddenly send SMS to some number at same time. The SMS log does not shows anything and sent SMS does not charge anything. But the popup dialog of charges comes which says "Last call charges 0.00, duration 60 secs".

This is strange as I checked all application, antivirus, backup, nothing is enabled related to tracking or something. I don't play games also, so my mobile is game free. Still my mobile suddenly gets up from sleep and send two SMS continuously everyday 2-3 times.

Not sure where SMS is going and as far as charges, it is not charged anything so that is relief but still bit worried on information leaking from my cell.

Please let me know if someone facing same issue and fixed on their mobile.

I feel it is related to Idea Network, but not sure. Interestingly the Avast virus scanner does not find any virus related activity.

It is IDEA Maharastra network, I checked with IDEA customer care, they denied for any such thing.

Hope someone will help.

Comment: You can refer to this question. It might help you out: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53005/my-phone-is-sending-sms-automatically-everyday

Answer (score 1):

First check Settings → for any app called *Idea Power* or *Idea Portal* or anything that you suspect is closely related to the cellular operator.

Mostly in Android devices with Idea SIM lock (CDMA) they install *Idea Power* system app. It is not visible in app manager especially for postpaid subscribers.

Not only Idea even other operators also do the same thing, but in Uninor and Airtel it will be too much.

2 of the most common signs are reduced battery life and while browsing sites too much of pay links and worst ads and operator ads, etc.

See when this operator app is installed it accesses your:

1. Phone information
2. Contacts
3. Rootkit
4. Send email without consent of host (user)
5. Read and write logs
6. Read memos
7. Directly call numbers and send msgs

THE LIST HAS SO MUCH MORE.

Finally in android 99.99% apps can be turned off except these operator injected secret code or app.

So I hope user only has to decide:

If its a second hand phone check if it is secured with mobile tracker of factory default or any tracking app preinstalled.

In AVG antivirus there are mobile tracking installs in hidden form and send email hidden even root format can't erase it which I once also used and got fed up with samsung galaxy young star pro, I guess its model no. is gt5372.